# Connecting Android App with Java Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, chord

I have searched around a little, but I couldn't find a complete answer on this, that's how I am asking. I have a Java Project of a messaging system, having implemented the server logic, using the implementation of the [Chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(peer-to-peer)), working as a distributed system.

I also have an Android app project, implemented for the use of the client gui, which I want to connect with my Java project in order to manage the proper requests and responses.

What is the best way to connect these two projects? My Java project is on the Eclipse IDE, and the app on the Android Studio. I know Android Studio uses a set of configurations and libraries, and since everything is Java, the correct way might only be to pass these configurations to Eclipse as well, and copy my android files there. But I am actually new to Java, and specifically the logic and the structure that it follows and I want to be sure of my actions, as I want to avoid going back and forth to this. I hope I gave all the right information, but you need me clarify anything else, just let me know. Btw, everything is local, there is no connection with external servers or any database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please specify the down votes? In order to understand if my question was vague or pointless and improve my way of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

For client requests to the server:
You can use one of the networking libraries for android - Volley/Retrofit for example. It shouldn't matter that your server is on the same computer, you will just need to adapt the url accordingly.

For messages from the server to the client without client requests:
You need Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out and see.